# Redirecting output from the Time command

Tags: bash, time, stdout

## Problem

I have a bash script that sets some environment variables before executing a program. That script is also recording the execution time of the program by running it through [GNU's time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html#GNU_VERSION) command. By default, time outputs to the stderr stream. I would like to declutter stderr to make relevant warnings and errors stand out, and therefore would like time to output to the stdout stream.

Using time's `--output=<filename>` and `-append` flags, I was able to output to /dev/stdout. I thought this was working until I tried to redirect the script's output to a file. When the script runs in the terminal everything seems fine, but when redirected to a file the time output is missing. Why is that happening, and is there a way to include time's double-redirected output within a file?

My operating system is: CentOS7

## Attempted Solutions

The script originally called the program using the default time command.

```bash
time program.exe
```

This has since been changed to use the GNU time command with options to specify outputting to a file, and to append instead of overwrite.

```bash
/usr/bin/time -p --output="/dev/stdout" --append program.exe
```

I have also tried wrapping this whole line within a code block.

```bash
{
    /usr/bin/time -p --output="/dev/stdout" --append program.exe
}
```

## Results So Far

When the script is called from the command line everything is correctly displayed. I get the output of the script, the program, and of time.

```
]$ script.sh params
> script output
> program output
> time output
]$
```

When I try to send the output to a file, time's output is missing.

```
]$ script.sh params > output.txt
]$ tail output.txt
> script output
> program output
]$
```

## Update

I tracked down the issue to a race-case within the script. The script traps the EXIT signal for cleanup, and echos some last minute information. The echos within the exit trap are writing over the output from time.

Trap example within script.sh:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

function script_cleanup {
    echo "debug msg"
}
trap script_cleanup EXIT

/usr/bin/time -p --output="/dev/stdout" --append sleep 2
```

When I shorted the echo messages within script_cleanup I saw that character for character the output was being overwritten.

```
]$ script.sh > output.txt
]$ tail output.txt
debug msgm2.068s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.046s
]$
```

I'm still not sure why this is happening, or how to get around it. But I'll update as I learn more.

## Update 2

I've tracked down my problem to an issue that has nothing to do with the time command.

The issue is with with writing to the stdout *file*, and then writing the the stdout *stream* afterwards. Here is an example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
printf "00000111112222233333" > /dev/stdout
printf "debug_msg"
```

With no script redirect the output looks fine.:

```
]$ ./example.sh
00000111112222233333debug_msg
]$
```

But when the script is redirected, output is cut off:

```
]$ ./example.sh > out.txt
]$ tail out.txt
debug_msg12222233333
]$
```

I have guesses, but I'm still not entirely sure why this is the behavior, nor do I know how to get around it.

Comment: To troubleshoot, put in script.sh `/usr/bin/time -p --output="/dev/stdout" --append sleep 2`

Comment: When I replace the timed program call with a timed sleep call I still don't get the time output. Only the script output shows up in the output.txt file.

Comment: Can you try to comment out everything in `script.sh` except `/usr/bin/time` line and run again ?

Comment: I created a blank `script.sh` with only the time sleep line. It successfully output the time to the file when I redirected it. So I'm guessing its something else in my real `script.sh` that's interfering. I'll futz with it and see what I can find, then I'll post an update. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't just miss the time output because it was skipped by `tail`?

Comment: @Armali The `time` output should be close enough to the bottom to see with `tail`. But I've also opened the output.txt files in a text editor to view the entire log. I'm just using `tail` as an example here to demonstrate the issue, and to keep the question from becoming too bloated. But now I wonder if I've left out too much information for the sake of brevity.

Comment: `but when redirected to a file the time output is missing.` I cannot reproduce. `to include time's double-redirected output within a file?` There is no "double" redirection - `time` is a program, and it outputs the stuff. The simplest is `--output=/the/file`. You can also  redirect last 3 lines of stderr to the flle, something along `/usr/bin/time -p sleep 2 2> >(tee >(tail -n3 >/the/file) >&2)`.